# Cómo corregir este problema con type:module en Javascript?

Tags: javascript, navegador-web

Sucede que quiero ejecutar código de javascript sin html en mi navegador pero me muestra lo siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y en mi package.json ya tengo "type":"module" pero me sigue apareciendo lo mismo

Comment: Bueno, te tocó mostrarnos el código que genera este error porque la adivinación no nos dió para resolver tu pregunta :) De hecho, la comunidad ya está votando para cerrarla por falta de info...

Answer (score -1):

Asume uno que estás usando algo que usa Node, verdad?

La solución de añadir `{type:module}` sólo funciona si usas Node versión 13 o superior. Si es inferior, puedes renombrar el .js donde hacer el import para que tenga extensión .mjs y lo corres con

```
node --experimental-modules tu-script.js
```

Otra opción es no hacer import en lo absoluto y usar algo del estilo

```
let module = await import('./external.js');
console.log(module.keyValue)
```

Comment: Tengo la versión 16 y no me funciona